# How to use the dark mode and selection modifier together in TailwindCSS?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, highlight, darkmode

I'm attempting to set the text highlight colors in my project that uses TailwindCSS. This can be done fairly easily using [the "selection" modifier that Tailwind provides](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#highlighted-text). This works fine except when I try to set different colors for dark mode. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong but I can't find anything online regarding how to correctly use the "dark" and "selection" modifiers in conjunction.

I tried the following syntax in attempt to get it to work correctly:

```
<html className="selection:bg-blue selection:text-purple dark:selection:bg-pink dark:selection:text-blue">
```

However, this only picks up the `selection:bg-blue selection:text-purple` styles and not the dark mode selection styles (`dark:selection:bg-pink dark:selection:text-blue`) when dark mode is activated.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

The colors do exist in my tailwind config:
[image]

Comment: I tried it online and it works fine. The only issue is that colors like `pink` or `blue` don't exist. You have to use `blue-900` and `pink-900` etc.

Comment: @Konrad - I forgot to mention that I do have those colors defined in my tailwind config. Would you mind sharing a link to your example? I haven't been able to make this work.

Comment: @Konrad - Figured this out and put an answer explaining what I was doing wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I wasn't thinking and realized what I was doing wrong was putting the selection classes on the HTML tag. The HTML tag is where the dark mode class gets applied and due to this, the selection class wasn't a descendant of the `.dark` mode class. To fix it, I moved the selection classes to the body tag.

Comment: So your example did not represent your actual code

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, why would my code above not be my code? Notice how the HTML tag has the selection modifier classes? You can not do this as the HTML is what gets the dark modifier. You must move it to the body (or lower).